# Learning .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like learn about .htaccess file, from the very basic to the complex portions. All its capacities, with blocking user, authentication, hiding files, redirection. So far I have only used them, but I want to learn about them, understand them. So that I will be able to create my own rule.

Could you please guide me through this, and point me to the basic and expert guides or lessons or even books. Anything, from basic to complex.

Comment: Should this be a community wiki?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here an "ultimate" [sample htaccess file](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html) and Apache's [rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: Afraid that I've never read any so I'm unable to recommend anything

Answer (score 25):

This page [more .htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) is the best simple introduction to using htaccess for rewriting and redirecting that I've found and it's easier to understand than the official Apache guide. You have to figure everything out from the examples, but it's a good selection of most of the common things you'd want to do, rewrite-wise.

Comment: No need to be sorry dude. Thanks for this Addition (+1)

Comment: You'll keep coming across Corz' pages on htaccess as they're concise, relevent and tackle common problems; definitely worth scanning so you have an idea of what can be achieved.