# How some websites doesn't show up page extension in the address bar?

Tags: url, web

Its just a question out of curiosity.

I have seen a lot of websites that doesn't show the page types/extensions in the address bar.For example, the stackoverflow's *Ask Question* page has the address `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` instead of something like `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.php`.

Do they use something to hide that page extension?Or why I do not see the page extension?

I think its a nice think for page security.

Comment: People use an HTaccess file to rewrite urls.. There is already a topic for this on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912673/learning-htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove file extension from website address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address)

Comment: -1; you would have found the answer by using a search engine first; there are also multiple duplicates on SO…

Answer (score 0):

using .htaccess file, you can do that

something similar here [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

A .htaccess (hypertext access) file is a directory-level configuration file supported by several web servers, that allows for decentralized management of web server configuration. They are placed inside the web tree, and are able to override a subset of the server's global configuration for the directory that they are in, and all sub-directories.

[htaccess file](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ultimate-htaccess-file-sample.html)

[Rewrite Guides](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

[More htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Rewrite Url

Servers often use .htaccess to rewrite long, overly comprehensive URLs to shorter and more memorable ones.

Authorization, authentication
A .htaccess file is often used to specify security restrictions for a directory, hence the filename "access". The .htaccess file is often accompanied by a .htpasswd file which stores valid usernames and their passwords

Given three links above these will explain you in better way.

Comment: [links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @feeela I was doing that Just edited the final one. Sorry for the late .

Answer (score 0):

All the `.htaccess` answers that you have seen apply to *traditional* PHP applications because they are all uploaded as normal files to the document root of a webserver.  This means that each PHP file is "browsable" directly, assuming you haven't prevented this at your webserver configuration.

StackOverflow (which is a .NET application) and other modern applications use a URL mapping paradigm - not only does this help with "clean" URLs, but also because [cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). It really doesn't have anything to do with security.

So it is most likely that each URL is *mapped* to a function, this function returns a response that is sent to the browser.

PHP frameworks offer the same - [Laravel routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing), [symfony routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) and [zend framework routing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) are all examples of this mapping paradigm.

Answer (score -1):

this is done by using the .htaccess file to configure the details of a website

example:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewrite Base /
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [NC,L]
```

this example rewrites a URL which looks like this `www.mydomain.com/home` into `www.mydomain.com?index.php&menu=home`

for more details please search stackoverflow / google