# How to creates routes, using Silex for webservice?

Tags: php, web-services, oop, silex

I need to implement a rest webservice and im with some dificults to understand how it works.

Client will make a call at 
http://server.domain.tld/version?id=127F0C05-F43C-4587-8736-1241F49F2E36&l=pt-PT&v=1.0.0&k=e2b5cabb27580217987c99b1a449e2dd56f1c8196d213e54915322bc0f542f36

On the webservice (Silex) i need to recognize this call:

```
$app->get('/version?id={guid}&l={language}&v={version}&k={token}', function ($guid) use ($app) {
$jsonResponse = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse();
$jsonResponse->setEncodingOptions(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$jsonResponse->setData(array());

return $jsonResponse;
});
```

Now i need to execute index.php and pass those values.

Quetions:
- How to redirect version to index.php by htaccess?
- How to catch GET variables ?

Comment: You'd have a route for `/version` and check the GET vars in the function. Though I wouldn't call this a RESTful API.

Comment: It's my first approuch. I'm learning yet :) What is the best way/location to stablish the route? htaccess? php file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912673/learning-htaccess)